# Android layout - 2 textview side by side wrap

Tags: android

I would like 2 TextViews side by side, with the overflow going underneath TextView1:

[image]

The problem experienced is that the two TextViews create two columns, which prevents the text of TextView2 from going underneath TextView1.

How would I do this?

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? Can you achieve the desired result using a single view and using SpannableString?

Comment: A would like show author name (bigger font) a description (normal font). Description is very long a must be under autor name. 2 colums is bad

Comment: Why is this question down voted? It is a valid question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout`to place your views related with the others.

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView1"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textview1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
    <TextView    android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="50"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
  <TextView  android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="50"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It is bad. Ted text is very long a must be under blue text. No 2 columns